# How to perform T9 search method in sql?

Tags: sql, search

I am new to sql database and currently I would like to do a database which can perform T9 search method, but I have no idea how to make it. Anyone can guide me on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: As in you want to implement predictive text? I imagine you want to use a tree in memory, not a database - I don't think that'd translate well to SQL.

Comment: Yes, I want to implement predictive text, that means using database itself is hard to perform t9 search is it? Thanks for your advice

Comment: I guess you just want a table with columns number representation, word, word priority. Because you want to search for `where number like '234%'` if there are no exact matches you probably need to keep the number a string - and that all just feels a bit messy to me.

Comment: +1 Interesting question, even if it seems a little misguided :-)

Comment: I not sure isit the correct ways, but I am using GLOB '[ABC][DEF]*' to search the words for dictionary, it can be used but i do not do any further testing, so currently i just using this method. anyone has any comment on this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android, I am using GLOB to perform T9 search, for example  GLOB '[ABC][DEF]*'

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, word, freq FROM dicttable WHERE word GLOB '"+searchWord+"*' ORDER BY freq DESC",
            null);
```

hope this can help

Comment: I think you're asking the database to do more work that it needs to - you can know in advance what the digits for each word is going to be so you don't need to do a wildcard match at runtime. My concern is that this will prevent the databases using indexes efficiently. I'd check the query execution plans for this - if it looks efficient, great, but otherwise you might have problems scaling the system to large volumes of look-ups.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't worry too much about efficiency, and have a table containing the entire dictionary in this form: Dictionary ([id],[hashed],[word])

Where the [hashed] field is a replacement of each character with its group symbol (e.g 'a','b', and 'c' can be replaced with 'A')

assume we have an 'hash' stored-function such that hash([word])=[hashed].

Then you can simply run this query:
`Select word from Dictionary where [hashed] like (hash(input)+'%')`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you ought to know, is the LIKE operator, for auto completion:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

SQL query isn't the best way for T9-style query.

There are more efficient data structure that support a scalable, robust solution for this kind of problem. (a Trie for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: Trie? But at any given node there'll be a number of different words so you'd need something more complicated than 'just add this letter' which is how tries normally work (you'd need at least 'add this letter to parent word X'). Plus you'll also need to store the 'best-match longer words' at nodes that have no exact matches otherwise you'll have to come up with a way to traverse the entire subtree to find these and order them, which isn't trie-like really.

Comment: In short, you'll need to use a trie on a hashing of the data. the exact implementation needs to be further investigated. in the mean-while, i suggested a less-efficient sql-based compromise in a different answer.